# Set up Selenium grid using Rselenium and Docker on one machine

Tags: r, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-grid, rselenium

Following Selenium Grid(https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2), I would like to run `n` browsers using RSelenium and Docker. I know how to start standalone chrome using docker. I have also found out how to use external cloud services (Sauce Labs and BrowserStack), but they are to expensive for me...

Should I first starthub and nodes from docker?

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hab selenium/hub:3.4.0
docker run -d --link selenium-hab:hub selenium/node-chrome:3.4.0
docker run -d --link selenium-hab:hub selenium/node-firefox:3.4.0
```

or should I just start first line and then start nodes using RSelenium?

Next, how should I start remote driver to make parallel automation on `n` defined nodes?
If I run remote drive usual way:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4444L, browserName = "chrome")
```

I don't get parallel execution.

Please help.
I am using R 3.4.3, Win 7.

Comment: One `remoteDriver` refers to a single browser. To run tests in parallel, you'll have to instanciate multiple  `remoteDriver`.

Comment: @Florent B., Do you have example in R or Python (or some other language) how to do this. If I run several remoteDrivers, what ports should it be, and how to parallelize in the end?

Comment: With parallel execution, the code always refer to the same server/hub (`192.168.99.100:4444` in your case). The hub will automatically dispatch the requests to the appropriate node depending on the session id. Parallel execution is usually handled by the testing library (see https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=python+parrallel+testing)

Comment: Thanks, I will google for more information. just one more question. Is it possible to run different selenium instructions for every browser?

Comment: Yes it's possible to execute a set of commands on all the nodes simultaneously. Though it will have to be handles by the testing library since the hub doesn't provide such features.